# Nativescript how to make http requests in the background

Tags: android, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

hi as I would like to be able to run some code when the app is closed
(for closed I mean closed by the task manager).
my app must be able to make http requests via axios in the background on both android and ios (must send notifications using the local-notification plugin that reminds that one or more events in an external calendar will start in an hour), I searched in network and I saw the documentation but it is not clear how I should do, I also read that the way to run background code on android 8 changes radically.
Can someone explain to me what I have to do? what permissions should I request from the system? or if there is any example of code on the net.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the samples for implementing background services for [iOS](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-background-execution) & [Android](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services).

There is also a plugin [nativescript-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/nativescript-background-fetch) which might work for you.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-background-fetch
```

Invokes your callback function roughly every 15 mins while the app is not alive, so you could finish your background activities like downloading your content etc.,

Comment: Hi, yes, this is what I was looking for.
But I have a problem, I installed the plugin but when the amount using             
import {BackgroundFetch} from "nativescript-background-fetch"                      
gives me this error: Cannot read property 'CompletitionHandler' of undefined

Comment: Is it a runtime exception or compile one?

Comment: runtime                                                                                                                             
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:

Answer (score 1):

Okay you should use a service in Android. It's a simple class that makes it happen in the background and after you're done you can stop the service. It works for android up to API v26 api. (26 not included). [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

For >=26 you can use Managers. There's a [downloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) already. But you don't have to use it, you can also use a Job Scheduler (>=lollipop).
There's a nice tutorial about it [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/schedule-tasks-and-jobs-intelligently-in-android-e0b0d9201777).

Also, read about using Android Background Services in NativeScript [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript).

Comment: @ChristopherCivitale No it's for android I added a new link for nativeScript at the end right now.

Comment: hello I saw the documentation but it is not clear to me one thing.
The example uses the tap event to start running in the background, how do I start the background service automatically without having to press the button?

Comment: You don't have to use a button.Start it whenever you want.on the start of the app.On server reply.On push notification.The limit is your imaginations.